# How to use react-native-navigation along with Create React Native App?

Tags: react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I couldn't find any information about how to install/use react-native-navigation with the Create React Native app project.

Anyone have experience with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be [this discussion](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/516) helps, and you will have a better idea what means to install a "native module" vs "normal module" (I invented both terms).

Remember that in one hand, native module its the one you have to configure in XCode and Android studio, modify gradle files, info.plist in iOS, etc, etc, these kind of modules works using operative system native apis, that improves a lot the speed and performance of your app, it's almost the same speed you would achieve programing the app in the native language for your mobile.

In the other hand normal modules, or Javascript modules work out of the box, if you have to configure something it will be only on the javascript side, no XCode, no Android Studio, nothing, but they don't have native "real native" support.

[CRNA official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) says:

> Create React Native App is the easiest way to start building a new
>   React Native application. It allows you to start a project without
>   installing or configuring any tools to build native code - no Xcode or
>   Android Studio installation required

Under the covers it will use [Expo](https://expo.io/), and limits you to only use "normal modules" or modules with expo support.

In order to get react-native-navigation support, you need to "yarn eject" your app to make it native compatible.